# Unity3D Coroutine compiler error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm a complete beginner in unity, and i'm tring to play an animation with a coroutine, but get the following erros:

1.error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(System.Collections.IEnumerator)' has some invalid arguments
2.error CS1503: Argument`#1' cannot convert `System.Collections.IEnumerable' expression to type`System.Collections.IEnumerator'

---

The code:

```
     using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Trap : MonoBehaviour {

    //public float delayTime;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine (Go ());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    IEnumerable Go(){
        while (true) {
            animation.Play();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Using the given answers also look at the error message you posted. That showed you what was wrong. Make it a point to learn to extract meaning  from error message. Depending on tbe editor you are using it may even suggest fixes.

Answer (score 6):

change

```
IEnumerable Go(){
    while (true) {
        animation.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    }
}
```

for a IEnumerator...

```
IEnumerator Go(){
    while (true) {
        animation.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to know why, the error is very clear... when you call StartCoroutine()  you need to add an argument of type: System.Collections.IEnumerator ... and because you declared "GO" as an IEnumerable, that's the reason why you're getting this error....

Comment: The names are so similar, it's a tough one to remember where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

The return type for an Coroutine will be IEnumerator.